# already using fillna, but still have null values in python

Tags: python

im using pycharm, i have column in df1 called Length_Employed. I planned to replace null values at that column into 0

so I did this

```
df1.Length_Employed.fillna(0, inplace=True) #  replace null values into 0 in Length_Employed column
```

but when i did `print(df1.isnull().sum(axis=0))`

why Length_Employed has not 0 values on it, where my wrong? and so does with another column that i want to replace null values into 0, why this change not happen?

Comment: Can you paste your df here? It is possible that the column values are not null but an empty string like ' ' which is why fillna won't work and you can use .replace

Comment: i think the problem is my column is not defined

Comment: idk, even i already paste it

Answer (score 0):

Something similar was happening to me, I still don't understand the causes, but I had to use the replace function in the following way.

```
df.column.replace({'':'text'})
```

Also use fillna ('text'). By using both, I was able to replace all the values.

It is not the best solution, but it has worked for me. This has only happened to me with text data, with numeric values I have not had this problem, yet.

I hope this information can help you.

Comment: ```''``` is my column or it just something like that?

Comment: Without seeing the data in the column, I consider that it may be your data. Maybe there is some empty string.